# Emmet not working inside divs

Tags: webstorm, emmet

I started using WebStorm and Emmet recently and I encounter a problem. For example typing

```
.row =>
<div class="row"></div>
```

Now if I type inside of that something else to generate more html it just wont work, like this:

```
<div class="row">
.col-md-5
</div>
```

just nothing happens.

EDIT: Ragavan Rajan Invalidating Cache and restarting solution works, but after a few minutes working Emmet gets broken again.

Comment: what is ur web storm version ?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of how that fragment looks there when it does not work (using Default color scheme)

Comment: when you hit the "Tab" inside div we would like to see what is happening on the screen. please post the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` didn't solve it.

But another way helped: I just unchecked the selected box in `Settings > Editor > Language Injections > "xml:div"`

[image: settings screen]

Answer (score 0):

Go to file > settings > search for Emmet [image]

Make sure you have checked the "Enable XML/ HTML Emmet"

Also, Go to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart -

Then Restart the web storm. Hope it helps

Comment: yes i have that enabled, .row works the thing is after im inside a div nothing else works, i got outside the div in the same file and it works a again

Comment: can you update your webstorm and restart the PC and give it a try please

Comment: Go to  File > Invalidate Caches / Restart - and give a  try

Comment: thanks File > Invalidate Caches / Restart solved it.

Comment: glad to help you!!

Comment: Update: what can be the reason? it keeps getting broken

Comment: i deleted the temp files it gets broken after a a few minutes

Comment: What is your web version please

Comment: Im currently using 2017.3.4